# "The company from Redmond" vs "The Redmond company."

Tags: style

I'm writing an article about Microsoft for my tech' analysis website and I got into a stylistic roadblock.

Which of the following sentences should I use?

> As I said before, the company from Redmond is cornered in the mobile space, so they'll need to heavily subsidize their OS in order to convince hardware manufacturers to join their fold.

> As I said before, the Redmond company is cornered in the mobile space, so they'll need to heavily subsidize their OS in order to convince hardware manufacturers to join their fold.

Comment: Just call them Microsquish and be done with it.

Comment: I think in practice you'd be more likely to see *"Redmond-based company"* rather than plain *"Redmond company"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In English, attributive adjectives usually precede their nouns in simple phrases"
source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective

That seems a fairly simple phrase so I would suggest "the Redmond company".

Also, given the familiarity of the company it is not some company from 
Redmond, it is *the* Redmond company.

It seems unnecessary and a little too informal to say "as I said before". If you
have the readers attention they will know what you have already said.

How about:

"The Redmond company is finding itself cornered in the mobile space, ..."

Answer (score 3):

So... provided that the reader has already been informed that they are reading about Microsoft, I prefer the first one (*the company from Redmond*).  It's nearly pejorative or at least tongue-in-cheek, and the phrasing reminds me of The Man From U.N.C.L.E.

The second version (*the Redmond company*) isn't confusing per se, but it won't scan with the impact of the first version.

Comment: I prefer "the company from Redmond" as well. As Sean notes above, it is *the* company from Redmond, and this also eliminates even the least confusion that you somehow might be talking about some other company which happens to be named "Redmond."

Answer (score 1):

It's "the Redmond-based company." There is no value in making the phrase longer.